# How can I simply test if the data for a web app will warn the user before being deleted by the browser?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

This is a follow-up question from [How do I make the data of a web app "persistent" as opposed to "best-effort"? I want to avoid the data being cleared when there is not enough space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51808081/5955911).

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API:

"If a box is marked as "persistent", the contents won't be cleared by the user agent without either the data's origin itself or the user specifically doing so. This includes scenarios such as the user selecting a "Clear Caches" or "Clear Recent History" option. **The user will be asked specifically for permission to remove persistent site storage units.**"

I guess I could try to add so much data until the DB is full but is there a simpler way to trigger this? It would be great for peace of mind.

Comment: Browsers use different schemes for allocating quota for storage to sites. At least in Chrome, though, you'll hit quota limits for a particular origin well before Chrome considers global storage full and starts evicting other origins on an LRU basis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of this but I was still hoping there would be an easy way to trigger it. I believe Chrome is caps an origin at 20% of global storage and I believe the global storage is 50% of the space left on the hard drive.